# Drop shadow form VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

So, I'm trying to add a strong shadow to my VB.NET form.
I already found a class here (https://github.com/wenerme/winform.DropShadow)

I translated the C# code to VB.NET but the thing is that I'm getting 5 errors:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpYqY.png

The translated code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Namespace AttendanceSystem

    Public Class Dropshadow
        Inherits Form

        Private _shadowBitmap As Bitmap

        Private _shadowOpacity As Single = 1

        Public Sub New(ByVal f As Form)
            Owner = f
            ShadowRadius = 10
            ShadowColor = Color.Black
            Dim wl As Integer = Win32.GetWindowLong(Handle, -20)
            wl = wl Or 524288 Or 32
            Win32.SetWindowLong(Handle, -20, wl)
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
            Owner.LocationChanged += AddressOf UpdateLocation
            Owner.FormClosing += Function(sender, eventArgs) Close()
            Owner.VisibleChanged += Function(sender, eventArgs)
                                        If Owner IsNot Nothing Then Visible = Owner.Visible
                                    End Function
        End Sub

        Public Property ShadowOffset As Point

        Public Property ShadowColor As Color

        Public Property ShadowBitmap As Bitmap
            Get
                Return _shadowBitmap
            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As Bitmap)
                _shadowBitmap = value
                SetBitmap(_shadowBitmap, ShadowOpacity)
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Property ShadowRadius As Integer

        Public Property BorderRadius As Integer

        Public Property ShadowOpacity As Single
            Get
                Return _shadowOpacity
            End Get

            Set(ByVal value As Single)
                _shadowOpacity = value
                SetBitmap(ShadowBitmap, _shadowOpacity)
            End Set
        End Property

        Protected Overrides Property CreateParams As CreateParams
            Get
                Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
                cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or 524288
                Return cp
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub UpdateLocation(ByVal Optional sender As Object = Nothing, ByVal Optional eventArgs As EventArgs = Nothing)
            Dim pos As Point = Owner.Location
            pos.Offset(ShadowOffset)
            pos.Offset(-ShadowRadius, -ShadowRadius)
            Location = pos
        End Sub

        Public Sub RefreshShadow(ByVal Optional redraw As Boolean = True)
            If redraw Then ShadowBitmap = DrawShadow()
            SetBitmap(ShadowBitmap, ShadowOpacity)
            UpdateLocation()
            Dim r As Region = Region.FromHrgn(Win32.CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, BorderRadius, BorderRadius))
            Dim [or] As Region = Owner.Region.Clone()
            [or].Translate(ShadowRadius, ShadowRadius)
            r.Exclude([or])
            Region = r
        End Sub

        Public Sub SetBitmap(ByVal bitmap As Bitmap)
            SetBitmap(bitmap, 255)
        End Sub

        Public Sub SetBitmap(ByVal bitmap As Bitmap, ByVal opacity As Single)
            SetBitmap(bitmap, CByte((opacity * 255)))
        End Sub

        Public Sub SetBitmap(ByVal bitmap As Bitmap, ByVal opacity As Byte)
            If bitmap.PixelFormat <> PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb Then Throw New ApplicationException("The bitmap must be 32ppp with alpha-channel.")
            Dim screenDc As IntPtr = Win32.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)
            Dim memDc As IntPtr = Win32.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDc)
            Dim hBitmap As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
            Dim oldBitmap As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
            Try
                hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0))
                oldBitmap = Win32.SelectObject(memDc, hBitmap)
                Dim size = New Win32.Size(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height)
                Dim pointSource = New Win32.Point(0, 0)
                Dim topPos = New Win32.Point(Left, Top)
                Dim blend = New Win32.BLENDFUNCTION()
                blend.BlendOp = Win32.AC_SRC_OVER
                blend.BlendFlags = 0
                blend.SourceConstantAlpha = opacity
                blend.AlphaFormat = Win32.AC_SRC_ALPHA
                Win32.UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, screenDc, topPos, size, memDc, pointSource, 0, blend, Win32.ULW_ALPHA)
            Finally
                Win32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDc)
                If hBitmap <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                    Win32.SelectObject(memDc, oldBitmap)
                    Win32.DeleteObject(hBitmap)
                End If

                Win32.DeleteDC(memDc)
            End Try
        End Sub

        Private Function DrawShadow() As Bitmap
            Dim fw As Integer = Owner.Width + ShadowRadius * 2
            Dim fh As Integer = Owner.Height + ShadowRadius * 2
            Dim gp = New GraphicsPath()
            gp.AddRectangle(New RectangleF(0, 0, fw, fh))
            Dim pgb = New PathGradientBrush(gp)
            pgb.CenterPoint = New PointF(fw / 2.0F, fh / 2.0F)
            pgb.CenterColor = ShadowColor
            pgb.SurroundColors = {Color.Transparent}
            Dim bitmap = New Bitmap(fw, fh)
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
            g.FillPath(pgb, gp)
            pgb.Dispose()
            gp.Dispose()
            Width = fw
            Height = fh
            Return bitmap
        End Function
    End Class

    Friend Class Win32

        Public Enum Bool
            [False] = 0
            [True]
        End Enum

        Public Const ULW_COLORKEY As Int32 = 1

        Public Const ULW_ALPHA As Int32 = 2

        Public Const ULW_OPAQUE As Int32 = 4

        Public Const AC_SRC_OVER As Byte = 0

        Public Const AC_SRC_ALPHA As Byte = 1

        <DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="CreateRoundRectRgn")>
        Public Shared Function CreateRoundRectRgn(ByVal nLeftRect As Integer, ByVal nTopRect As Integer, ByVal nRightRect As Integer, ByVal nBottomRect As Integer, ByVal nWidthEllipse As Integer, ByVal nHeightEllipse As Integer) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll")>
        Public Shared Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function UpdateLayeredWindow(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hdcDst As IntPtr, ByRef pptDst As Point, ByRef psize As Size, ByVal hdcSrc As IntPtr, ByRef pprSrc As Point, ByVal crKey As Int32, ByRef pblend As BLENDFUNCTION, ByVal dwFlags As Int32) As Bool
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function GetDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
        Public Shared Function ReleaseDC(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hDC As IntPtr) As Integer
        End Function

        <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function CreateCompatibleDC(ByVal hDC As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function DeleteDC(ByVal hdc As IntPtr) As Bool
        End Function

        <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
        Public Shared Function SelectObject(ByVal hDC As IntPtr, ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        End Function

        <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
        Public Shared Function DeleteObject(ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Bool
        End Function

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
        Private Structure ARGB

            Public ReadOnly Blue As Byte

            Public ReadOnly Green As Byte

            Public ReadOnly Red As Byte

            Public ReadOnly Alpha As Byte
        End Structure

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
        Public Structure BLENDFUNCTION

            Public BlendOp As Byte

            Public BlendFlags As Byte

            Public SourceConstantAlpha As Byte

            Public AlphaFormat As Byte
        End Structure

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
        Public Structure Point

            Public x As Int32

            Public y As Int32

            Public Sub New(ByVal x As Int32, ByVal y As Int32)
                Me.x = x
                Me.y = y
            End Sub
        End Structure

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
        Public Structure Size

            Public cx As Int32

            Public cy As Int32

            Public Sub New(ByVal cx As Int32, ByVal cy As Int32)
                Me.cx = cx
                Me.cy = cy
            End Sub
        End Structure
    End Class
End Namespace
```

I am trying to know what's causing this, any help will be appreciated since I'm trying to fix this for hours.
Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem my friend... Did you finally find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here (That is C# code, not VB.Net):

```
  Owner.LocationChanged += AddressOf UpdateLocation
  Owner.FormClosing += Function(sender, eventArgs) Close()
  Owner.VisibleChanged += Function(sender, eventArgs)
                                        If Owner IsNot Nothing Then Visible = Owner.Visible
                                    End Function
```

In Vb.Net you need this syntax:

> AddHandler event, AddressOf eventhandler

Example:

> AddHandler Owner.LocationChanged, AddressOf UpdateLocation

More here: [AddHandler Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement)

Comment: Or with a Lambda: `AddHandler Owner.LocationChanged, Sub(sender, e)  (...) End Sub`

Comment: Sorry for my silliness but, what do I have to change/add? I'm kinda new in VB.NET so I'm sorry if I don't understand some of those codes... Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I managed to convert it. Even commented parts of code!!! I tested it and it's working 100%. You can find the converted class **[here](https://github.com/simonetos/vb.net_winform_dropshadow/blob/master/DropShadowDemo/DropShadow.vb)**, or your can download the whole project from **[here](https://github.com/simonetos/vb.net_winform_dropshadow)** and see how it works.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D

''' <summary>
''' Dropshadow.
''' Add a shadow to a WinForm.
''' </summary>
Public Class DropShadow
    Inherits Form

    '((( VARIABLES )))
    Private _shadowBitmap As Bitmap
    Private _shadowColor As Color
    Private _shadowH As Integer
    Private _shadowOpacity As Byte = 255
    Private _shadowV As Integer

    '((( PROPERTIES )))
    Public Property ShadowColor() As Color
        Get
            Return _shadowColor
        End Get
        Set
            _shadowColor = Value
            _shadowOpacity = _shadowColor.A
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ShadowBitmap() As Bitmap
        Get
            Return _shadowBitmap
        End Get
        Set
            _shadowBitmap = Value
            SetBitmap(_shadowBitmap, ShadowOpacity)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ShadowOpacity() As Byte
        Get
            Return _shadowOpacity
        End Get
        Set
            _shadowOpacity = Value
            SetBitmap(ShadowBitmap, _shadowOpacity)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ShadowH() As Integer
        Get
            Return _shadowH
        End Get
        Set
            _shadowH = Value
            RefreshShadow(False)
        End Set
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Offset X relate to Owner.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property OffsetX() As Integer
        Get
            Return ShadowH - (ShadowBlur + ShadowSpread)
        End Get
    End Property
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Offset Y relate to Owner.
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property OffsetY() As Integer
        Get
            Return ShadowV - (ShadowBlur + ShadowSpread)
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Width() As Integer
        Get
            Return Owner.Width + (ShadowSpread + ShadowBlur) * 2
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Shadows ReadOnly Property Height() As Integer
        Get
            Return Owner.Height + (ShadowSpread + ShadowBlur) * 2
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Property ShadowV() As Integer
        Get
            Return _shadowV
        End Get
        Set
            _shadowV = Value
            RefreshShadow(False)
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property ShadowBlur() As Integer
    Public Property ShadowSpread() As Integer
    Public Property ShadowRadius() As Integer
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            '((( This form has to have the WS_EX_LAYERED extended style. )))
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H80000
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property

    '((( EVENTS )))
    Public Sub New(ByVal f As Form)
        Owner = f
        ShadowColor = Color.Black
        '((( Default style. )))
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
        ShowInTaskbar = False
        '((( Bind event. )))
        AddHandler Owner.LocationChanged, Sub(sender, eventArgs) UpdateLocation()
        AddHandler Owner.FormClosing, Sub(sender, eventArgs) Close()
        AddHandler Owner.VisibleChanged, Sub(sender, eventArgs)
                                             If Owner IsNot Nothing Then
                                                 Visible = Owner.Visible
                                             End If
                                         End Sub
        AddHandler Owner.Activated, Sub(sender, args) Owner.BringToFront()
    End Sub
    Public Sub UpdateLocation(Optional sender As [Object] = Nothing, Optional eventArgs As EventArgs = Nothing)
        Dim pos As Point = Owner.Location
        pos.Offset(OffsetX, OffsetY)
        Location = pos
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Refresh shadow.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="redraw"> (optional) redraw the background bitmap. </param>
    Public Sub RefreshShadow(Optional redraw As Boolean = True)
        If redraw Then
            'ShadowBitmap = DrawShadow()
            ShadowBitmap = DrawShadowBitmap(Owner.Width, Owner.Height, 0, ShadowBlur, ShadowSpread, ShadowColor)
        End If
        'SetBitmap(ShadowBitmap, ShadowOpacity)
        UpdateLocation()
        '((( Set the display area. )))
        Dim r As Region = Region.FromHrgn(Win32.CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0, Width, Height, ShadowRadius, ShadowRadius))
        'Dim r As New Region(New Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height))
        Dim [or] As Region
        If Owner.Region Is Nothing Then
            [or] = New Region(Owner.ClientRectangle)
        Else
            [or] = Owner.Region.Clone()
        End If
        [or].Translate(-OffsetX, -OffsetY)
        r.Exclude([or])
        Region = r
        Owner.Refresh()
    End Sub
    ''' <para>Changes the current bitmap with a custom opacity level. Here is where all happens!</para>
    Public Sub SetBitmap(bitmap As Bitmap, Optional opacity As Byte = 255)
        If bitmap.PixelFormat <> PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb Then
            Throw New ApplicationException("The bitmap must be 32ppp with alpha-channel.")
        End If
        '((( The idea of this is very simple. )))
        '((( 1. Create a compatible DC with screen. )))
        '((( 2. Select the bitmap with 32bpp with alpha-channel in the compatible DC. )))
        '((( 3. Call the UpdateLayeredWindow. )))
        Dim screenDc As IntPtr = Win32.GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)
        Dim memDc As IntPtr = Win32.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDc)
        Dim hBitmap As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Dim oldBitmap As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
        Try
            hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0))
            '((( Grab a GDI handle from this GDI+ bitmap. )))
            oldBitmap = Win32.SelectObject(memDc, hBitmap)
            Dim size As New Win32.Size(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height)
            Dim pointSource As New Win32.Point(0, 0)
            Dim topPos As New Win32.Point(Left, Top)
            Dim blend As New Win32.BLENDFUNCTION()
            blend.BlendOp = Win32.AC_SRC_OVER
            blend.BlendFlags = 0
            blend.SourceConstantAlpha = opacity
            blend.AlphaFormat = Win32.AC_SRC_ALPHA
            Win32.UpdateLayeredWindow(Handle, screenDc, topPos, size, memDc, pointSource, 0, blend, Win32.ULW_ALPHA)
        Finally
            Win32.ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDc)
            If hBitmap <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Win32.SelectObject(memDc, oldBitmap)
                '((( The documentation says that we have to use the Windows.DeleteObject. But since there is no such method, I use the normal DeleteObject from Win32 GDI and it's working fine without any resource leak. )))
                'Windows.DeleteObject(hBitmap)
                Win32.DeleteObject(hBitmap)
            End If
            Win32.DeleteDC(memDc)
        End Try
    End Sub

    '((( FUNCTIONS )))
    Public Shared Function DrawShadowBitmap(width As Integer, height As Integer, borderRadius As Integer, blur As Integer, spread As Integer, color As Color) As Bitmap
        Dim ex As Integer = blur + spread
        Dim w As Integer = width + ex * 2
        Dim h As Integer = height + ex * 2
        Dim solidW As Integer = width + spread * 2
        Dim solidH As Integer = height + spread * 2
        Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(w, h)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
        '((( Fill background. )))
        g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(color), blur, blur, width + spread * 2 + 1, height + spread * 2 + 1) ' +1 to fill the gap
        If blur > 0 Then
            '((( Four dir gradiant. )))
            If True Then
                '((( Left. )))
                Dim brush As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New Point(blur, 0), Color.Transparent, color)
                '((( Will thorw ArgumentException. )))
                ' brush.WrapMode = WrapMode.Clamp
                g.FillRectangle(brush, 0, blur, blur, solidH)
                '((( Up. )))
                brush.RotateTransform(90)
                g.FillRectangle(brush, blur, 0, solidW, blur)
                '((( Right. )))
                '((( Make sure parttern is currect. )))
                brush.ResetTransform()
                brush.TranslateTransform(w Mod blur, h Mod blur)
                brush.RotateTransform(180)
                g.FillRectangle(brush, w - blur, blur, blur, solidH)
                '((( Down. )))
                brush.RotateTransform(90)
                g.FillRectangle(brush, blur, h - blur, solidW, blur)
            End If
            '((( Four corners. )))
            If True Then
                Dim gp As New GraphicsPath()
                gp.AddEllipse(0, 0, blur * 2, blur * 2)
                'gp.AddPie(0,0,blur*2,blur*2, 180, 90)
                Dim pgb = New PathGradientBrush(gp)
                pgb.CenterColor = color
                pgb.SurroundColors = {System.Drawing.Color.Transparent}
                pgb.CenterPoint = New Point(blur, blur)
                '((( Left top corner. )))
                g.FillPie(pgb, 0, 0, blur * 2, blur * 2, 180, 90)
                '((( Right top corner. )))
                Dim matrix As New Matrix()
                matrix.Translate(w - blur * 2, 0)
                pgb.Transform = matrix
                'pgb.Transform.Translate(w-blur*2, 0)
                g.FillPie(pgb, w - blur * 2, 0, blur * 2, blur * 2, 270, 90)
                '((( Right bottom corner. )))
                matrix.Translate(0, h - blur * 2)
                pgb.Transform = matrix
                g.FillPie(pgb, w - blur * 2, h - blur * 2, blur * 2, blur * 2, 0, 90)
                '((( Left bottom corner. )))
                matrix.Reset()
                matrix.Translate(0, h - blur * 2)
                pgb.Transform = matrix
                g.FillPie(pgb, 0, h - blur * 2, blur * 2, blur * 2, 90, 90)
            End If
        End If
        Return bitmap
    End Function
End Class



Friend Class Win32 '((( Class that exposes needed win32 gdi functions. )))

    Public Enum Bool
        [False] = 0
        [True]
    End Enum

    Public Const ULW_COLORKEY As Int32 = &H1
    Public Const ULW_ALPHA As Int32 = &H2
    Public Const ULW_OPAQUE As Int32 = &H4
    Public Const AC_SRC_OVER As Byte = &H0
    Public Const AC_SRC_ALPHA As Byte = &H1

    '((( x-coordinate of upper-left corner.  )))
    '((( y-coordinate of upper-left corner.  )))
    '((( x-coordinate of lower-right corner. )))
    '((( y-coordinate of lower-right corner. )))
    '((( Height of ellipse. )))
    <DllImport("Gdi32.dll", EntryPoint:="CreateRoundRectRgn")>
    Public Shared Function CreateRoundRectRgn(nLeftRect As Integer, nTopRect As Integer, nRightRect As Integer, nBottomRect As Integer, nWidthEllipse As Integer, nHeightEllipse As Integer) As IntPtr
        '((( Width of ellipse. )))
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function GetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Changes an attribute of the specified window. The function also sets the 32-bit (long) value at the specified
    ''' offset into the extra window memory.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="hWnd">A handle to the window and, indirectly, the class to which the window belongs..</param>
    ''' <param name="nIndex">
    ''' The zero-based offset to the value to be set. Valid values are in the range zero through the
    ''' number of bytes of extra window memory, minus the size of an integer. To set any other value, specify one of the
    ''' following values: GWL_EXSTYLE, GWL_HINSTANCE, GWL_ID, GWL_STYLE, GWL_USERDATA, GWL_WNDPROC
    ''' </param>
    ''' <param name="dwNewLong">The replacement value.</param>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' If the function succeeds, the return value is the previous value of the specified 32-bit integer.
    ''' If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
    ''' </returns>
    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function SetWindowLong(hWnd As IntPtr, nIndex As Integer, dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function UpdateLayeredWindow(hwnd As IntPtr, hdcDst As IntPtr, ByRef pptDst As Point, ByRef psize As Size, hdcSrc As IntPtr, ByRef pprSrc As Point,
            crKey As Int32, ByRef pblend As BLENDFUNCTION, dwFlags As Int32) As Bool
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function GetDC(hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Public Shared Function ReleaseDC(hWnd As IntPtr, hDC As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function
    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function CreateCompatibleDC(hDC As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function DeleteDC(hdc As IntPtr) As Bool
    End Function
    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True)>
    Public Shared Function SelectObject(hDC As IntPtr, hObject As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function
    <DllImport("gdi32.dll", ExactSpelling:=True, SetLastError:=True)>
    Public Shared Function DeleteObject(hObject As IntPtr) As Bool
    End Function
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
    Private Structure ARGB
        Public ReadOnly Blue As Byte
        Public ReadOnly Green As Byte
        Public ReadOnly Red As Byte
        Public ReadOnly Alpha As Byte
    End Structure
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
    Public Structure BLENDFUNCTION
        Public BlendOp As Byte
        Public BlendFlags As Byte
        Public SourceConstantAlpha As Byte
        Public AlphaFormat As Byte
    End Structure
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure Point
        Public x As Int32
        Public y As Int32
        Public Sub New(x As Int32, y As Int32)
            Me.x = x
            Me.y = y
        End Sub
    End Structure
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure Size
        Public cx As Int32
        Public cy As Int32
        Public Sub New(cx As Int32, cy As Int32)
            Me.cx = cx
            Me.cy = cy
        End Sub
    End Structure
End Class
```